# tcpreplay installation failed, libpcap/collect

Tags: tcpreplay

I could not install tcpreplay on RHEL 6.6

When I try to run ./configure I got following error

```
checking for inet_addr... yes
checking for libpcap... no
configure: error: libpcap not found

[root@tcpreplay-4.1.0]# ldconfig -p | grep libpca
        libpcap.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libpcap.so.1
[root@tcpreplay-4.1.0]#
```

ldconfig output shows that there is installed libpcap

I also tried with --with-libpcap=/usr/lib64    option but I got same error.

I have another RHEL 6.6 with similar config, I uninstalled tcpdump, libpcap with yum. Installed latest libpcap and tcpdump from tarball without error. I got no error on ./configure command of tcpreplay tarball. (In this installation libpcap installed into /usr/local/lib)

But when I try to make I got following error.

```
/usr/local/lib/libpcap.a(pcap-dbus.o): In function `dbus_activate':
/directory/libpcap-1.7.4/./pcap-dbus.c:185: undefined reference to `dbus_connection_open'
/directory/libpcap-1.7.4/./pcap-dbus.c:191: undefined reference to `dbus_bus_register'
/directory/libpcap-1.7.4/./pcap-dbus.c:230: undefined reference to `dbus_bus_add_match'
/directory/libpcap-1.7.4/./pcap-dbus.c:231: undefined reference to `dbus_error_is_set'
/directory/libpcap-1.7.4/./pcap-dbus.c:232: undefined reference to `dbus_error_free'
/directory/libpcap-1.7.4/./pcap-dbus.c:235: undefined reference to `dbus_bus_add_match'
/directory/libpcap-1.7.4/./pcap-dbus.c:236: undefined reference to `dbus_error_is_set'
/directory/libpcap-1.7.4/./pcap-dbus.c:238: undefined reference to `dbus_error_free'
/usr/local/lib/libpcap.a(pcap-dbus.o): In function `dbus_cleanup':
/directory/libpcap-1.7.4/./pcap-dbus.c:143: undefined reference to `dbus_connection_unref'
/usr/local/lib/libpcap.a(pcap-dbus.o): In function `dbus_activate':
/directory/libpcap-1.7.4/./pcap-dbus.c:169: undefined reference to `dbus_bus_get'
/directory/libpcap-1.7.4/./pcap-dbus.c:178: undefined reference to `dbus_error_free'
/directory/libpcap-1.7.4/./pcap-dbus.c:227: undefined reference to `dbus_connection_set_max_received_size'
/directory/libpcap-1.7.4/./pcap-dbus.c:176: undefined reference to `dbus_bus_get'
/usr/local/lib/libpcap.a(pcap-dbus.o): In function `dbus_cleanup':
/directory/libpcap-1.7.4/./pcap-dbus.c:143: undefined reference to `dbus_connection_unref'
/usr/local/lib/libpcap.a(pcap-dbus.o): In function `dbus_activate':
/directory/libpcap-1.7.4/./pcap-dbus.c:193: undefined reference to `dbus_error_free'
/usr/local/lib/libpcap.a(pcap-dbus.o): In function `dbus_write':
/directory/libpcap-1.7.4/./pcap-dbus.c:114: undefined reference to `dbus_message_demarshal'
/directory/libpcap-1.7.4/./pcap-dbus.c:120: undefined reference to `dbus_connection_send'
/directory/libpcap-1.7.4/./pcap-dbus.c:121: undefined reference to `dbus_connection_flush'
/directory/libpcap-1.7.4/./pcap-dbus.c:123: undefined reference to `dbus_message_unref'
/directory/libpcap-1.7.4/./pcap-dbus.c:116: undefined reference to `dbus_error_free'
/usr/local/lib/libpcap.a(pcap-dbus.o): In function `dbus_read':
/directory/libpcap-1.7.4/./pcap-dbus.c:70: undefined reference to `dbus_connection_read_write'
/directory/libpcap-1.7.4/./pcap-dbus.c:66: undefined reference to `dbus_connection_pop_message'
/directory/libpcap-1.7.4/./pcap-dbus.c:83: undefined reference to `dbus_message_is_signal'
/directory/libpcap-1.7.4/./pcap-dbus.c:88: undefined reference to `dbus_message_marshal'
/directory/libpcap-1.7.4/./pcap-dbus.c:100: undefined reference to `dbus_free'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [tcpreplay] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/directory/tcpreplay-4.1.0/src'
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/directory/tcpreplay-4.1.0/src'
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/directory/tcpreplay-4.1.0/src'
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

Do you have any idea / solution to install tcpreplay

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

```
sudo apt-get install tcpreplay
```